# Can't define libsdl2 dependency in my Debian package proper way

Tags: linux, debian, packaging, sdl-2, deb

I've written a small graphic fun app, which is using SDL2. I've packaged it into a *.deb* package, everything is working, except dependencies. I have only one dependency, *libsdl2-image* (it will refer to *libsdl2*, anyway, it has the same problem), but it works only if I describe it the following way (in `DEBIAN/control` file):

```
Depends: libsdl2-image-2.0-0
```

I don't really like it, it will be broke next week or next month, when libsdl-image-2.1 comes out.

This one would be better, but it does not work:

```
Depends: libsdl2-image (>= 2.0)
```

Even this would be so-so, but it also does not work:

```
Depends: libsdl2-image
```

I've tried other libs (with some common ones), and they work, just as the manual promised. I've tried it on two machines (an amd64 and a i386), both fail same way. I've tried with *libsdl2* (the SDL2 core), it plays the same game.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest answer: you want to use the first dependency line you mentioned.

Yes, your .deb won't work with `libsdl2-image-2.1`, but that's going to be the case no matter what you do. This is the reason that library packages need to be named according to the SONAME of the library they contain; a change in SONAME indicates you must (at a minimum) rebuild the executable to work with the new version. But you can expect that `libsdl2-image-2.0-0` won't go away anytime soon.

If I've misunderstood the concern, and you're actually worried about your *packaging* still working with a newer version of libsdl2-image, then the right solution (as with most Debian packaging tasks) is to use Debhelper instead of trying to create the package at the lowest possible level.

With Debhelper, you'd have a `debian/control` instead of a `DEBIAN/control`, and it might look something like:

```
Source: my-graphic-fun-app
Other-Fields: blah
Build-Depends: libsdl2-image-dev (>= 2.0.0)

Package: my-graphic-fun-app
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: It's fun and it's graphic!
```

So you'd only be declaring that your package needs `libsdl2-image-dev` present to be built (2.0.0 or any later version). Once it is built, a tool inside the Debhelper guts called `dh_shlibdeps` will analyze the resulting executable and substitute in the right information in the "`${shlibs:Depends}`" variable. When the new version of libsdl2 comes out, you could install the corresponding version of `libsdl2-image-dev` and make a new version of your .deb, and the new one would depend on `libsdl2-image-2.1` instead.